# Defined Variable Returning Run-time 1004

Tags: excel, variables, range, moving-average, vba

I'm getting a Run-time 1004 error "Application-defined or object-defined error" when I use the following code:

```
Sub GetPCData()

'Get PC response ratios

PCanalytes = Array("Furosemide", "Caffeine", "Ketoprofen", "Phenylbutazone", "Flunixin")
PCanalytePositions = Array("J20", "K20", "L20", "M20", "N20")

Set SQWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

Dim sourceSheet, targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim copyFromRange, copyToRange As Range
Dim Y As Range

Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("QC data")

For i = 0 To SQWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    Set sourceSheet = SQWorkbook.Worksheets(PCanalytes(i))
    Set Y = sourceSheet.Range("H8").End(xlDown)
    Set copyToRange = targetSheet.Range(PCanalytePositions(i))
    Set copyFromRange = sourceSheet.Range("H8", Y)
    copyToRange.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(copyFromRange)
    copyToRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Next i

End Sub
```

I need to use the values in two cells H8 and the variable defined as Y within the defined arrays to calculate an average. So I need the average of two separate cells one of which is a variable that will be defined by the data set being processed with this macro. Sorry if this is a simple fix, I haven't been able to figure out a way around it.

Comment: Which line? Try `Set copyFromRange = sourceSheet.Range("H8", sourceSheet.Range("H8").End(xlDown))`

Comment: Yes! @SJR, that is the line where the error throws

Comment: Whenever you don't include a sheet reference, the active sheet is assumed and if that is different from sourceSheet you will get an error as a range cannot straddle two sheets.

Comment: Using that thread of code didn't throw an error, but the values that are being calculated are all values between H8 and Y. I need it to only average H8 and Y, and omit the cells that fall between them.

Comment: You don't define Y anywhere. Is it a single cell? You are averaging all the cells from H8 down currently.

Comment: At one point it was defined and used within the range above but I kept running into the original Run-time 1004 error, so I tried writing the range without referencing a variable. It looked like this. 
Dim Y As Range

Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("QC data")

For i = 0 To SQWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    Set sourceSheet = SQWorkbook.Worksheets(PCanalytes(i))
    Set Y = sourceSheet.Range("H8").End(xlDown)
    Set copyToRange = targetSheet.Range(PCanalytePositions(i))
    Set copyFromRange = sourceSheet.Range("H8", Y)

Comment: Code in comments doesn't work, as you can see ...

Comment: Yes I realize, which is why I was trying to find a different way of referencing a variable location within a range. Is that not possibe using VBA?

Comment: No I'm not referring to functionality, but that it is unreadable in comments - add to your question please. In essence are you trying to average H8 and the last cell if you move down from H8?

Comment: So sorry! I updated the post with the code that I had tried at first. Problem is there are cells with content within column H past Y that I do not want included in this function, which is why I was trying to use xlDown to determine Y. I could also use an offset function to reference this location if that makes it easier to exclude the other data found in column H

Comment: I've suggested an answer below so let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works as I have made an assumption about what you are trying to achieve.

```
Sub GetPCData()

Dim PCanalytes, PCanalytePositions

'Get PC response ratios
PCanalytes = Array("Furosemide", "Caffeine", "Ketoprofen", "Phenylbutazone", "Flunixin")
PCanalytePositions = Array("J20", "K20", "L20", "M20", "N20")

Set SQWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet, targetSheet As Worksheet 'note you need to add the type for each declaration
Dim copyFromRange As Range, copyToRange As Range       'ditto
Dim Y As Range

Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("QC data")

For i = 0 To SQWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    Set sourceSheet = SQWorkbook.Worksheets(PCanalytes(i))
    Set copyToRange = targetSheet.Range(PCanalytePositions(i))
    Set copyFromRange = sourceSheet.Range("H8", sourceSheet.Range("H8").End(xlDown))
    With copyFromRange
        copyToRange.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(.Cells(1), .Cells(.Cells.Count))
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thank you for being patient with me @SJR